# Entity recognition with context/relation

Tags: named-entity-recognition

Is there a way to get a specific entity based on the context where it is found?
For example:

The temperature today is `35°C`.

Store risperidone tablet at `20°C`.

Both are talking about temperature. For the first sentence, I would want the temperature to be a "WeatherTemperature" entity. In the second sentence, I would want the temperature to be "DrugTemperature". What model could I use to train for this behavior?

Comment: This is related to the tasks of topic modeling and/or word sense disambiguation. But it completely depends on what kind of data you can use for training.

Comment: @Erwan How should I first proceed? Is there a particular tool I can use? I have a lots of  lines of text that are like this. "Store X at Y°C, Keep X at Y°C, Freeze X at Y°C" and I would like distinct entities for them.

Comment: If you don't have any annotated data, it's Word Sense Discrimination (WSD): the idea is to clusterize occurrences of "Y°C" based on the context words represented as a vector. There are probably existing tools but I don't have any specific recommendation.

Comment: @Erwan Thank you! I have some researching to do now.

Answer (score 0):

With [Wolfram Language](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/) you may use [`TextCases`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TextCases.html) or [`TextContents`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TextContents.html) from the [Text Analysis guide](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/TextAnalysis.html).  These are both experimental functions so may change a bit before they are finalised in a future version.  Both have the [`TargetDevice`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TargetDevice.html) option so you can run them on one or more GPUs if you have them.

Reference the [Text Content Types guide](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/TextContentTypes.html) for the list of entities these functions have been trained on.

I think `TextContents` is an optimised call to `TextCases` for multiple cases so I will only use `TextContents` below.

Use `TextContents` to locate all trained entities in your sentences.

```
res1 = TextContents["The temperature today is 35°C.", TargetDevice -> "GPU"]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

```
res2 = TextContents["Store risperidone tablet at 20°C.", TargetDevice -> "GPU"]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

`TextContents` returns a [`Dataset`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dataset.html) object that can be [`Query`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Query.html)'ed for specific cases.

For example for your "DrugTemperature"

```
res2[ContainsAll[{"Chemical", "Quantity"}], "Type"]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

and the quantity units

```
res2[
  SelectFirst[#["Type"] == "Quantity" &], 
  "String" /* SemanticInterpretation /* QuantityUnit]
```

> ```
> "DegreesCelsius"
> ```

An [`Entity`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Entity.html) of type [`"Chemical"`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/entity/Chemical.html) has a wealth of properties so additional information can be obtained if needed.  For example,

```
res2[
 SelectFirst[#["Type"] == "Chemical" &], 
 "String" /* Interpreter["Chemical"] /* (#["MoleculePlot"] &)]
```

> [image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: This looks rather promising. What are you using to do this? I tried the Wolfram Client Library for Python but I can't seem to find any of the things (TextContents, TextCases) I need. Are they still in preview?

Comment: @AvinashPrabhakar The above is in a [Wolfram notebook](http://www.wolfram.com/notebooks/) as you didn't specify a platform. For Wolfram Client for Python you need to download the [Free Wolfram Engine here](http://www.wolfram.com/developer/). Then you'll be able to use [Wolfram Language](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/) in Python. You won't have the dynamic interactivity of a Wolfram notebook but you will have access to all the functions. I have a few recent answers here on SE.DS that demonstrate Wolfram Language in Python.